# AS3.0 variable declaration with numbers in row

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have many variables which are letter + number. Is it possible to state variables with for loop?
Compiler says it has an error 1084 missing identifier. I am not sure what identifier means.

```
        for(i=1;i>14;i++){
            var "P"+i:MovieClip = new "p"+i();
            var "R"+i:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500 , 500);
            var "D"+i:Bitmap = new Bitmap();    
        }
```

instead of

```
    var P1:MovieClip = new p1();
    var P2:MovieClip = new p2();
    var P3:MovieClip = new p3();

    var R1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500 , 500);
    var R2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500 , 500);
    var R3:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500 , 500);

    var D1:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
    var D2:Bitmap= new Bitmap();
    var D3:Bitmap= new Bitmap();
```

Comment: Learn to use arrays. [Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee1.html)

Comment: @haruka.k - Did you get it figured out?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done the way you want, but I'd say it's rather sloppy architecture:

```
    for(i=1;i>14;i++){
        this["P"+i] = new (getDefinitionByName("p" + i) as Class);
        this["R"+i] = new BitmapData(500 , 500);
        this["D"+i] = new Bitmap();    
    }

    //to test if it worked
    trace(this.P1, this.R1, this.D1);
```

Not knowing what you intend do with those sets of three objects, it's hard to recommend a cleaner solution,  but perhaps creating a container class would be clean and easy:

1. Create a class file (text file),  let's call it `PContainer.as` and save it in the same directory as your .fla file.
2. Use this as the contents of the class file:

   ```
   package {
       import flash.display.Sprite;
       import flash.display.BitmapData;
       import flash.display.Bitmap;
       import flash.display.MovieClip;

       public class PContainer extends Sprite {
           //create three properties for this class
           public var bitmapData:BitmapData;
           public var bitmap:Bitmap;
           public var mc:MovieClip; //this assumes your P1 class is a movie clip
           //this function runs when you do `new PContainer()`
           public function PContainer(id:int):void {
               bitmap = new Bitmap();
               bitmapData = new BitmapData(500,500);

               var cls:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName("p" + id) as Class;

               mc = new cls();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use the class like this:

   ```
   //create an array to hold all of them:
   var pArray:Array = [];

   //loop and create all the items
   for(i=1;i<14;i++){
       pArray.push(new PContainer(i));
   }

   //to access item 2, you'd do something like this: (arrays are zero based)
   trace(pArray[1].mc);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @BadFeelingAboutThis.

But you can also use Vectors, so you are sure that each Vector contains the specified objects.
I don't know why you want or need to name those instance "P1 -> Pn"...
If you really need it to do so, the code here bellow is useless.

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

var p:Vector.<MovieClip> = new Vector.<MovieClip>();
var r:Vector.<BitmapData> = new Vector.<BitmapData>();
var d:Vector.<Bitmap> = new Vector.<Bitmap>();

for(var i=1;i<14;i++){
// NOT for(i=1;i>14;i++)
    var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500 , 500);
    var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(); 
    p.push(mc);
    r.push(bmd);
    d.push(bm);
}

var testIndex:uint = 5;

trace(("p"+testIndex.toString()) + " = " + p[testIndex]);
trace(("r"+testIndex.toString()) + " = " + r[testIndex]);
trace(("d"+testIndex.toString()) + " = " + d[testIndex]);

/*
output:
p5 = [object MovieClip]
r5 = [object BitmapData]
d5 = [object Bitmap]
*/
```

You should add a try and catch block to see if the index is in the Vector range.
Check the [Vector reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html)